# Postfix rejects email routed from Google Workspace: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[209.85.128.69]: 451 4.3.0 Temporary lookup failure

Tags: email, postfix, g-suite

Setting up Google Workspace and want to test things before changing the production MX records and having everything go through Google. I have a test Workspace account for domain testdomain.tld. I have set up an email route from testdomain.tld in Workspace pointing to the company's legacy mail server mail.corporate1.com. The legacy server is postfix 2.11.3-1 running on an old Debian (Wheezy/Jessie) server.

The route configuration in Workspace is shown at the bottom. This route is to test the advertised ability to route unrecognized email addresses to the legacy server. We need to use this capability to migrate the users and automated email streams gradually.

The email gets routed nicely, but the legacy Postfix mail server does not accept the email. The test I am running is to send email from outside the company to testuser@testdomain.tld and watch the logs on mail.corporate1.com. Tried many different configuration changes and I just keep getting the same error message in the mail log. The test user does not have an account in the testdomain.tld Workspace, a test condition. The test user is set up as a Linux user on corporate1.com and successfully receives email addressed to testuser@corporate1.com. The error, main.cf, and mail route config follow below.

-------error from mail log-------

```
Sep 19 12:34:56 [postfix/submission/smtpd] NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[209.85.128.69]: 451 4.3.0 <testlocation@wherever.com>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<testlocation@wherever.com> to=<testuser@testdomain.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ab1-c23.google.com>
```

-------main.cf---on mail.corporate1.com-------

```
myhostname = server.corporate1.com
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.corporate1.com, mail.corporate0.com, corporate0.com, corporate1.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain, corporate2.com, mail.corporate2.com, server.corporate2.com, server.corporate0.com, server0.corporate0.com, server.corporate1.com, server0.corporate1.com, corporate3.com, mail.corporate3.com, testdomain.tld
relayhost =
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
command_execution_directory = $home

masquerade_classes = envelope_recipient, envelope_sender,
        header_sender, header_recipient
masquerade_domains = corporate0.com corporate1.com

mynetworks = 10.0.0.0/8, 127.0.0.0/8, 177.177.77.0/24, 24.213.146.72/29.
        178.178.45.16/28.
        179.254.122.0/24.
        170.170.113.143/32.
        171.171.57.10/32.
        174.129.81.250/32.
        172.172.69.27/32.
        173.173.106.89/32.
        [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104, [::1]/128

mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 0
command_time_limit = 45m
ipc_timeout = 45m

recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
# inet_protocols = ipv4

# Alias and recipient maps

alias_maps = hash:/etc/mail/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/mail/aliases
# Default local_recipient_maps
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps

# SSL

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/usr/asher/certificates/mail.corporate1.com.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/usr/asher/certificates/server0_priv.pem
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3

proxy_interfaces=177.177.77.118

# SASL
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
# smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
# smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
## Allow plaintext mechanisms, but only over a TLS-encrypted connection:
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
#smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
# smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unauth_destination
#       reject_unknown_recipient_domain
## Keep these ???
#smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/controlled_envelope_senders
smtpd_sender_login_maps =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unauth_destination
#       reject_unknown_recipient_domain
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = corporate1.com

luser_relay = non-deliverable@corporate1.com

smtp_defer_if_no_mx_address_found = yes

# anti-spam experiment
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 9
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 19

relay_domains = mail.corporate1.com
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

# DKIM
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action = accept

virtual_alias_domains = corporate2.com
```

-------google-workspace email route configuration-------

```
Admin > Apps > Google Workspace > Gmail > Routing
   Name:
      Pass-Through Email Delivery for Unrecognized Addresses
   1. Email messages to affect
      * Inbound
      * Internal - Receiving
   2. For the above types of messages, do the following
      * Route
         * Change route
         * Also reroute spam
         * (To:) Legacy Email Server
   Options
   B. Account types to affect
      * Users
      * Unrecognized / Catch-all
```

Answer (score 0):

The virtual table was missing.  Created an empty /etc/postfix/virtual and ran command:

```
    postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```